# FlowJs - class is incompatible with interface it implements while used in array

Tags: flowtype

I come from C# background and trying to do the thing that would work there, but for some reason does not work with flow js.

I have interface and a class that implements interface:

```
interface Id {
    id: number
}

class A implements Id {
    id: number
}
```

When I try to use object of a class in place of interface this way, everything works:

```
var a = new A()
function f(v: Id) {}

f(a)
```

But when I try to use array of objects, it gives me an error:

```
var array: Array<A> = [ new A(), new A() ]
function f(array: Array<Id>){}

f(array)
```

Error is:

> 'Id (This type is incompatible with A)'

Why is that?

Comment: Oh man it's not just me, I would love an answer to this :(